# Angular :: src_app_app_routing_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppRoutingModule.redirectToLogin is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to redirect from my home page to login page using home.component.ts
In this file I have called a static method " AppRoutingModule.redirectToLogin()" which I have implemented in app-routing.module.ts using Router import.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R579u.png)

Please check my code

home.component.ts

Check AppRoutingModule.redirectToLogin() method call

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from 'src/app/service/location.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  //Variables to be used in the html file
  stringifiedData: string[] = [];
  Location: any;
  booking = {
    from !: "",
    to !: "",
    date !: ""
  }

  fetchLocation()
  {
    this.GetRequest.fetchLocation().subscribe(data => {
      this.Location = data;
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.Location).length; i++)
      {
        this.stringifiedData.push(this.Location[i].locationName);
      }
    });
  }
  getBookingFormData()
  {
    if (this.validateForm())
    {
      let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      if (currentUser == null)
      {
        alert("Please login to book a trip");
        AppRoutingModule.redirectToLogin();

      }
    }
  }
  validateForm()
  {
    if (this.booking.from == "" || this.booking.to == "" || this.booking.date == "")
    {
      alert("Please fill in all the fields");
      return false;
    }
    else if (this.booking.from == this.booking.to)
    {
      alert("Please select different destinations");
      return false;
    }
    else if (this.booking.date < new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])
    {
      alert("Please select a future date");
      return false;
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log(this.booking);
      return true;
    }
  }

  constructor(private GetRequest : LocationService) { 
    try {
      this.fetchLocation();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './Componentes/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './Components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './Components/signup/signup.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login/signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  static redirectToLogin: any;
  constructor(private router: Router)
  {

  }
}

function redirectToLogin() : void
{
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
}
```

Comment: Why not just inject the router in your component and do it there..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function is not inside the class, so it cannot be called as a class element!

It should be something like:

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './Componentes/home/home.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './Components/login/login.component';
    import { SignupComponent } from './Components/signup/signup.component';
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'login/signup', component: SignupComponent },
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
      constructor(private router: Router)
      {
    
      }
    
      redirectToLogin() : void
      {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    
    }
```

And then inject AppRoutingModule in the constructor of your component and call the method using it like:

**home.component.ts**

```
constructor(private GetRequest : LocationService,
            private appRoutingModule : AppRoutingModule) { 
    try {
      this.fetchLocation();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  }
```

And in the function:

```
getBookingFormData()
  {
    if (this.validateForm())
    {
      let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      if (currentUser == null)
      {
        alert("Please login to book a trip");
        appRoutingModule.redirectToLogin();

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Using the router as a DI’d class is not possible in a static function.

Comment: You are right, i did not notice it.

Comment: @ManuelTomás my home.component.ts construction is showing error when I am passing Router as parameter. So what should I do to redirect to login page